# how to view specific setting page in **winrt** application using C#?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

how to view specific setting page in **winrt** application using C# from outside button click?

In javascript i found like this  *WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.showSettings("About", "/Settings/About.html")*

But i could not able to find this in c#,I am using **callisto** for Setting Flyouts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using Callisto and C# too, and this is how I solved the problem.

```
    void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var settings = new SettingsCommand("settings", "Settings", new UICommandInvokedHandler(showSettings));
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(settings);
        var credits = new SettingsCommand("credits", "Credits", new UICommandInvokedHandler(showCredits));
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(credits);
    }

    public void showSettings(IUICommand command)
    {
        var settings = new SettingsFlyout();
        settings.Content = new SettingsUserControl();
        settings.HeaderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(_background);
        settings.Background = new SolidColorBrush(_background);
        settings.HeaderText = "Settings";
        settings.IsOpen = true;
    }

    public void showCredits(IUICommand command)
    {
        var settings = new SettingsFlyout();
        settings.Content = new CreditsUserControl();
        settings.HeaderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(_background);
        settings.Background = new SolidColorBrush(_background);
        settings.HeaderText = "Credits";
        settings.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Then from other pages I can just call

```
((App)Application.Current).showCredits(null);
```

or

```
((App)Application.Current).showSettings(null);
```

To bring up the settings pane I want to see :o)

Comment: @pashaplus - if you're happy with this answer could you accept it please? :o)

Comment: I did the same thing, but it doesn't work if I want to show the settings pane in a "Grid Loaded" event: the charms-settings-pane appears, BUT the commands I add aren't shown! Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to add a listener for the CommandsRequest event on the SettingsPane for the page where you want the setting to be displayed. For example:

```
SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += MainPage_CommandsRequested;
```

Then define the event handler

```
void MainPage_CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    SettingsCommand generalCommand = new SettingsCommand("GeneralSettings", ResourceLoader.GetString("GeneralText"), (x) =>
    {
        SettingsFlyout settings = new SettingsFlyout();
        settings.HeaderBrush = Resources["SettingsHeaderBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
        settings.HeaderText = ResourceLoader.GetString("GeneralText");
        settings.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
        settings.Content = new GeneralSettingsFlyout();
        settings.IsOpen = true;
        settings.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;

        // Optionally, add a closed event handler
        settings.Closed += settings_Closed;
    });
}
```

Note that in this scenario, GeneralSettingsFlyout is simply a Page which will be loaded into the settings pane once that particular setting is selected (Callisto automatically handles this).

SettingsFlyout is the class from Callisto.

Comment: My question is not that,in your example to open **general settings** we need select the particular setting command from setting pane but i want to open **general settings** page from outside button click

Answer (score 0):

**Edit your app.xaml file and reference this snippet for your code:**

```
App::OnLaunched()
{
.
.
     var rootFrame = new CharmFrame { CharmContent = new CharmFlyouts() };
     SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "AppFrame");
.
.
}
```

**Then, when you want to display that setting, do this:**

```
SomeOtherMethod()
{
     ((Window.Current.Content as CharmFrame).CharmContent as CharmFlyouts).ShowSettings();
}
```