# How to open any specific SettingsFlyout in WinRT app

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am working on a Windows 8 metro app and having multiple SettingsFlyout items which get added by below mentioned code

```
SettingsCommand cmd1 = new SettingsCommand("sample", "Color Settings", (x) =>
        {
            // create a new instance of the flyout
            SettingsFlyout settings = new SettingsFlyout();
            // set the desired width.  If you leave this out, you will get Narrow (346px)
            // optionally change header and content background colors away from defaults (recommended)
            // if using Callisto's AppManifestHelper you can grab the element from some member var you held it in
            // settings.HeaderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(App.VisualElements.BackgroundColor);
            settings.HeaderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            settings.HeaderText = string.Format("Color Settings", App.VisualElements.DisplayName);
            settings.Background = new SolidColorBrush(_background);
            settings.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            // provide some logo (preferrably the smallogo the app uses)
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(App.VisualElements.SmallLogoUri);
            settings.SmallLogoImageSource = bmp;

            // set the content for the flyout
            settings.Content = new ColorSettings();
            settings.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            // open it
            settings.IsOpen = true;

            // this is only for the test app and not needed
            // you would not use this code in your real app
            // ObjectTracker.Track(settings);
        });
```

Currently using (SettingsPane.Show()) i can be able to show the added flyout items list but I want to programmatically open any setting Flyout item instead of opening a flyout list.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760142/how-to-view-specific-setting-page-in-winrt-application-using-c/14743712#14743712). may be this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class

```
public class SettingsFlyout
{
    private const int _width = 346;
    private Popup _popup;

    /// <summary>
    /// Show the Flyout with the UserControl as content
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control"></param>
    public void ShowFlyout(UserControl control)
    {
        _popup = new Popup();
        _popup.Closed += OnPopupClosed;
        Window.Current.Activated += OnWindowActivated;
        _popup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
        _popup.Width = _width;
        _popup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;

        control.Width = _width;
        control.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;

        _popup.Child = control;
        _popup.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Window.Current.Bounds.Width - _width);
        _popup.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);
        _popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void OnWindowActivated(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.WindowActivationState == Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
        {
            _popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    void OnPopupClosed(object sender, object e)
    {
        Window.Current.Activated -= OnWindowActivated;
    }
}
```

In a XAML page take a button and then write the button click event.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SettingsFlyout flyout = new SettingsFlyout();
    flyout.ShowFlyout(new FlyoutContentUserControl());
}
```

Please note one thing `FlyoutContentUserControl` is the user control which you would like to show.

Credits goes to [Q42.WinRT](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted registers a `SettingsCommands` to the system settings pane.  When your command is invoked from the system settings pane, you new up a `SettingsFlyout` instance and set `IsOpen=True` on it.

You just need to refactor this code to a separate method (e.g. `ShowColorSettingsFlyout()`), and also call that method from your `Button.Click` event handler.  You can create a new Callisto `SettingsFlyout` and set `IsOpen=True` on it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml.cs add the following to register your [SettingsFlyout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.settingsflyout.aspx) e.g. CustomSetting ...

```
protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
{
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;
}

private void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(
            "Custom Setting", "Custom Setting", (handler) => ShowCustomSettingFlyout()));
}

public void ShowCustomSettingFlyout()
{
    CustomSetting CustomSettingFlyout = new CustomSetting();
    CustomSettingFlyout.Show();
}
```

Then anywhere in your code you want to programmatically open the CustomSetting flyout, call ShowCustomSettingFlyout, e.g. in the event handler for a button click...

```
void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowCustomSettingFlyout()
}
```

Adapted from: [Quickstart: Add app settings (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh872190.aspx).